# Is there an alternative to k3dsurf in 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, qt3

I've just upgraded to Quantal Quetzal on my home computer and discovered that the program K3dSurf has been removed from the repositories. (Presumably since it doesn't seem to be in active development and still depends on qt3 libraries.)
Does anyone know of a similar program (user-friendly and versatile) for drawing 3D surfaces? This has been a mission-critical program for me when teaching multivariable calculus, so I won't be able to upgrade at work unless I can find a replacement. 
(Yes, I could install directly from the program's website, but dealing with obsolete libraries sounds like a giant headache.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can install it using the following packages from Debian Squeeze:
[k3dsurf](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/k3dsurf) and [libqt3-mt](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/libqt3-mt).

It works well.

Comment: That's a sneaky one. It seems to not have any real Qt3 libraries, but just the qt3-mt one which does not have other Qt3 dependencies on its own. `:-)`

Comment: Nice! Thanks. If I had research funds right now I'd be tempted to throw a bag of money at someone willing to keep this thing in development. It's the best tool of its kind I've come across.

Answer (score -2):

Just to say that now there is a new replacement to K3DSurf, check this [discussion](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2209820) for more informations.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: All you asked for IS THERE is the answear :) ...

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at that thread. With Ubuntu 13.10 there was some change to (I'm guessing) the way Qt3 was handled that made K3DSurf look horrible, so a replacement that functions properly would be amazing.

Comment: MathMod is a Qt5 application and this opens a lot more opportunities of development of height end GUI, especially in the mobile area. This said, future developments will focus on the ease of use and usefulness. So, all your comments and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Correction: "high-end GUI". I can't find how to edit my response!